# $watch not working when i remove an element from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array "aQuestions"
When i delete an element from this array im using $watch on aQuestions but the $watch is not getting triggered.
Here is the functionto remove the element from the array

```
$scope.fnRemoveRow = function(rowId) {
        getCandidateInterviewListService.fnDeleteQuestions(rowId)
            .then(function(response) {
                angular.forEach($scope.aQuestions, function(value, key) {
                    if (value == response)
                        $scope.aQuestions.splice($scope.aQuestions.indexOf(value), 1);
                });
            });
    };
```

and im using $watch like below

```
$scope.aQuestions = [];
    $scope.$watch(
        "aQuestions",
        function fncheckQuesCount() {
            getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetQList($scope.sTopic).then(function(response) {
                $scope.aQuestionList = response;
            });
        }, true);
```

here even though the element is getting removed from aQuestion ,$watch is not getting triggered.

Comment: Since you're using `$scope.$watch(...,true)` it should work unless there is some scope issue and you're watching something else. Can you create an [mcve]?

Comment: here i m using equality=true so it should work because it checks the deep changes but the $watchCollections checks the shallow ones

Comment: Yeah it  *should* work but if it isn't then you should create a minimal demo with the problem which we can debug... It could be a scope issue.

Comment: Don't you have to call $digest (since this is an async operation)?

Comment: why there is the necessity to call here $digest?

Comment: If `fnDeleteQuestions` use an angular service directly, you don't have to call `$digest`. But if the async operation does not use an angular service, you have to call it.

Comment: even after keeping $watchCollections its not working